# Django Rest Framework Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using `django-rest-auth` with `django-all-auth` on DRF and Angularjs. On any request regarding auth, I get the following error:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Going through SO, i've realised there are a lot of similar problems so accumulating them together, I tried the following:

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
   ),
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

REST_SESSION_LOGIN = False
```

My `app.js` file

```
sgApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/static/partials/index.html',
            controller: 'indexCtrl'
        }).when('/abc',{
            templateUrl: 'static/partials/index.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }
]).controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $http, $httpProvider){
       $scope.login = function() {
           Facebook.login(function(response) {
            var postDict = {
                access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken
            }
            $http.post('/sgAuth/facebook/', postDict).
                success(function(data){
                    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + data.key;
                    $scope.loggedIn = true;
                    $scope.userDetails(); //function that gets user details
                });
        });
    };
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does logging in work? Can you see the `data.token` if you log it to the console? Does the `Token` header appear in the request if you look in your browser's developer tools (F12)?

Comment: @KevinBrown, it is very arbitrary. It'll work sometimes, but it won't logout. And if it does logout, I can't login again.

Comment: Just to factor it out, I would try adding a console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken) before your call to your own API login. I would also make sure your Token is populating correctly as suggested by Kevin Brown. If FB is working correctly but your token is missing, then you need to check out your logs.

Comment: I have the same issue here.

Comment: @ItaloMaia, Hey, what's the problem you're facing? I sort of fixed it, so I might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in your line:

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + data.key;

Try this:

httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + data.key;

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have permission class in your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
   ),
}
```

So only requests made by admin user are going through.