# Django Rest Framework allauth Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am using django `allauth` for authentication

this is my `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
}
```

the installed app are these:

```
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
'rest_auth.registration',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
```

and i am trying like way:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/cinema-hall/" -H 'Authorization: Token 44eba1cdb1ecde6d3a55d6c85d7c4f44315f2c44'
```

this error i am getting:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I see many similar post exist like this: [Django Rest Framework Authentication credentials were not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043310/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided)

but those are not solved my issue.

Can anyone tell me what is the possible reason of facing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with using CURL to test an api, but is it possible that 'Authorization' is misspelled as 'Authorizaion'?

Edit: after your response confirming that's not the case, I noticed that you have both TokenAuthentication and SessionAuthentication in the default authentication classes. Either remove SessionAuthentication or add the required credentials (cookie containing session details and csrf token).

Comment: No, It's not misspillied in real curl. I have edited the post, pelase check